# how to regex.replace in a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm a newbie at programming, looking for some help. I'm doing a program in c# that translates a text from a language "x" (let's say spanish for example") to english. I need to use this dictionary of dictionaries:

```
var PLANG = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>();

PLANG["en"] = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 11, "Name" },
    { 20, "Surname (" }
};

PLANG["es"] = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 11, "Nombre" },
    { 20, "Apellido (" }
};
```

For translating the text, i need  to replace each value from the corresponding key. I'm trying this code, but it's not working:

```
foreach (int Indice in PLANG["es"].Keys)
{
    TextToTranslate = Regex.Replace(TextToTranslate, PLANG["es"][Indice], PLANG["en"][Indice]);
}
```

This is not working, and i don't know why. The program compiles fine, but when i execute it for debugging i'm getting "System.ArgumentException".
EDIT: The problem occurs on the lines with parenthesis in the dictionaries, key 20.

Comment: Nobody never reads exception messages :( What is the message of `System.ArgumentException` in your case?

Comment: I actually copied and pasted your exact code and worked for me.

Comment: @vasily.sib are you sure nobody reads exceptions? Maybe they are there, just to bother us and tell us our code is terrible?

Comment: I edited the question. The exception occurs with the values of the strings in the dictionaries that contain parenthesis, that would be key 20 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it adding a `Regex.Escape`:

```
foreach (int Indice in PLANG["es"].Keys)
{
    TextToTranslate = Regex.Replace(TextToTranslate, Regex.Escape(PLANG["es"][Indice]), PLANG["en"][Indice]);
}
```